# reactjs Inline-Style gridColumn not respecting span

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to use `span` to allow the events using `grid-column` to spread across multiple days in a calendar, but this seems to only work in css or styled-components. It does not work in inline-styles. Anyone have any idea to make this work with inline-styles?

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-event-calendar-8v9o1?file=/src/Components/CalendarEvent.js

Code Snippet:

```
    <span
      className="calendar-event-label"
      styled={{gridColumnStart: col, gridColumnEnd: `span ${colSpan}`}}
      onClick={onClick}
    >{title}</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Style` instead of `Styled`

```
style={{
        gridColumnStart: col,
        gridColumnEnd: `span ${colSpan}`
      }}
```

I checked the changes in the code sandbox it works.

Working: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-event-calendar-forked-4s0h9

Comment: Ah thank you, this was definitely it. As soon as 9mins passes I can mark this as the answer.